# Using jQuery to animate the visibility of a div when clicking navigation link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery and I currently have a jQuery function that drops a div from a hidden position when you click on a div box. this works fine with a css div as parameter, but when I try to parse two navigation links as parameters it doesn't work.

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

I want to replace `.logobox` with a `<a href>` link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.logoBox').toggle(function(){
        $('.lowerContainer').slideDown();
    }, function(){
        $('.lowerContainer').slideUp();
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the code snippet that's not working:

> `<script type="text/javascript">
>       $(document).ready(function(){
>           $('<a href="C:\Users\home.html">Home</a>').toggle(function(){
>               $('.lowerContainer').slideDown();
>           }, function(){
>               $('.lowerContainer').slideUp();
>           });
>       });
>       </script>`

Comment: Please show the code that doesn't work instead of the one that does.

Comment: its a selector you cannot pass links instead you can put the class logoBox in the link like <a class="logoBox" href=""></a> and u dont have to change your js code

Comment: you can use [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uUyFy/) to replace an element

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.logoBox').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.lowerContainer').slideDown();
  });
  $('.logoBox').mouseleave(function(){
     $('.lowerContainer').slideUp();
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: The solution above is good but I wanted the slide down to occur when you click on a <li><a href="#">link1</a></li> instead of a class or mouseenter event.

Comment: can u send me a sample $('.logoBox').clik(function(){$('.lowerContainer').slideDown();??